# Exception "No successful match so far" after Matcher.find() == true

Tags: java, regex

```
Matcher m = patternFoo.matcher(sFoo);

if(m.find()){
    ...
    m.start()
    ...
}
```

I wonder how it is possible for the `m.start()` in the above code to throw the following exception:

```
Exception: No successful match so far
Class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:1116)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:1158)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:1130)
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?

**Update [2024-02-08]**

`m` is a local variable accessed by only one thread.

This problem is reported by the analytics of an app with hundreds of thousands of installations. It is rare but it happens.

I have started to wonder if this is caused by OutOfMemory which does happen much more often than this error (probably caused by some codecs) though OutOfMemory is still very rare.

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example? Odd's are you did something in the `...` that broke the code. Did you call `m.reset();`?

Comment: One possibility is that a new value has been assigned to `m` between the `find` and `start` calls.  Another one is that something has called `reset` on the `Matcher`.  And if `m` or the `Matcher` assigned to it are visible to multiple threads, there are all sorts of ways this could mess up.

Comment: Hint: using an inappropriate tag like `[untagged]` is a good way to stop people from noticing your questions.  If that is not your intent (!!) I'd advise not doing it.

Comment: And sampling your other recent questions ... "bad tagging" is a plausible explanation why you didn't get answers (or even comments) for so many of them.  The right people (i.e. those who can answer) are simply not noticing them.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips. I am quite sureuntagged is not what I added. As far as I know, I always added tags to my questions. I had the impression tagging was a requirement for questions on SO. Let me recall the tags and add them to this question, so you will see my original tags. I have a consistent way in choosing tags.

Comment: @StephenC I tried to restore my original tags but failed. Here is my hunch: I normally make the tag as specific as possible and avoid general tags such as java, android, I thought I would find tags like android-regex, java-regex that were likely what I originally used, but I failed to find them. I cannot help wondering if some of these tags were removed recently and this is why you saw "untagged" that I had never heard of.

Comment: That is what "untagged" is described as. Were you still going to try and get an answer to this question? There are two suggestions for how you could get such a result. Or maybe you have an answer from how you did solve it?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this problem. The problem is reported by the analytics of an app with hundreds of thousands of installations. It is rare but it happens. Matcher m is a local variable, so it is impossible for more than one thread to access it. I will edit the question in a moment to provide more information.